# Query users by custom taxonomy and user role

Tags: custom-taxonomy, user-roles, terms, user-meta, wp-user-query

I'm trying to make a query for users using `WP_User_Query()`
I need to filter users by role `shop_manager` and custom taxonomy called `shop-category` and current taxonomy term ID.

The code I have so far:

```
<?php 

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'role'           => 'shop_manager',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'orderby'        => 'user_registered',
    'tax_query' => array(
    array('taxonomy' => 
    'shop-category', 
    'field' => 'id', 
    'terms' => $term_id ) ) 
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<li><span>' . esc_html( $user->shop_name ) . '</span></li>';
    }
} else {
    // no users found
}

?>
```

To get term ID I was using this code

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; 

echo 'ID = '. $term_id;?>
```

Now it's showing all users with `shop_manager` role. Looks like taxonomy doesn't work.

Comment: What plugin are you using for the shop?

Comment: I'm using WooCommerce plugin.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently there is no core implementation of `'tax_query'` in `WP_User_Query` yet.

Check the ticket here for more info --> https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31383

Nevertheless there is an alternative way using `get_objects_in_term`

```
$taxonomy = 'shop-category';
$users = get_objects_in_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );    

if(!empty($users)){

    // WP_User_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'role'           => 'shop_manager',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'orderby'        => 'user_registered',
        'include'        => $users
    );

    // The User Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // The User Loop
    if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
        foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
            echo '<li><span>' . esc_html( $user->shop_name ) . '</span></li>';
        }
    } 
    else {
        // no shop_manager found 
    }
}
else {
    // no users found
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `tax_query` parameter for the `WP_User_Query` class. Since you've tagged the question with `user-meta` I can only assume you store the `ID` (or even the term name itself?) of a particular `shop-category` term as a user meta entry.

In this case you would need something like this:

```
// The 'WP_User_Query' arguments array
$args = array(
    'role'          => 'shop_manager',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'orderby'       => 'user_registered',
    'meta_key'      => 'shop_name', // Is this the meta key you are using?
    'meta_value'    => 'the_term_name_or_term_id', // Based on however you store your meta data
    'meta_compare'  => '=',
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm slowly getting there.Yes i'm using term ID. For Example: 
Taxonomy is "shop-category"
Term name: gits, accessories, perfumery, etc...
I was trying to pass the term ID in the query.

Will try with meta_key now...

Comment: @Erik Please note that my initial code had a hyphen instead of an underline in `'shop_name'`. You should pay attention to what you actually need, don't just copy / paste things in general. :)

Comment: @Erik Did you managed to make it work? Note that you can try to set the `meta_compare` argument like so:`'meta_compare' => 'like'` in case you don't get the wanted results.

Comment: If you use meta data then @webtoure's answer is fine. If you use taxonomies follow mine.